# How do i retrieve user first name? (yii2)

Tags: php, mysql, yii2

Sorry I am new to yii2 I am trying so hard to get used to it :(
I really just want to display my user's first name rather than his ID and cannot understand what I must do to retrieve due to the fact that the ID is in one table and the name is in another. This is my db and code:

I have got 3 tables:

tbl_user_notification:

```
id(PK), comment
```

tbl_user_notification_users:

```
id(PK), n_id (FK), user_id (FK)
```

tbl_user:

```
id(PK), first_name, last_name.
```

In the index page of notification, I want to display the comment (from tbl_user_notification) and the first and last names of the users the notification was sent to (from tbl_user).

I am only managing to display the ID on the index page however. How can I show the name pls?

**Notification model:**

```
    public function getNotifUsers()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(NotificationsUsers::className(), ['n_id' => 'id']);
    }
```

**My notification index page:**

```
GridView::widget([
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
            'filterModel' => $searchModel,
            'columns' => [
                ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
                //'id',
                [
                    'label' => 'First Name',
                    'value' => 'notifUsers.user_id',
                ],
                'comments',
(etc)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I presume the join function below is in the UserNotification model and you are joining it to the UserNotificationUser model.

```
   public function getNotifUsers()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(NotificationsUsers::className(), ['n_id' => 'id']);
    }
```

So now that you have a join to the UserNotificationUser model, you need to join THAT model to the User model because it has the user_id.

Solution: From within **userNotificationUser** model, add a new function:

```
   public function getUser()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(User::className(), ['id' => 'user_id']);
    }
```

Then within the Gridview you simply call the join sequentially - first notifUser then user then a user attribute:

```
GridView::widget([
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
            'filterModel' => $searchModel,
            'columns' => [
                ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
                'notifUsers.user.first_name'
                // or
                [
                    'label' => 'First Name',
                    'value' => 'notifUsers.user.first_name',
                ],
                'comments',
```

Comment: OMG TYY!!! Finally!! It was so simple and i was stuck on it for so long omg but finally thanks to you i've done it! Thankyou <3